# Matplotlib not clearing old plots when updating figure

Tags: python, matplotlib-widget, python-interactive

I have a code to plot points and to update the number of points in X,Y with a slider.

There is no way I can make the old plots disappear in the update function, tried all possible variations of .clear() and so on...

Here is my code; comments are some of the things I tried...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button,Slider
import numpy as np

#- setup default grid values
nx = 100
ny = 50
dx = 10


X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,nx*dx,nx+1),np.linspace(0,ny*dx,ny+1))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

axnx = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
axny = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])

NX = Slider(axnx, 'nx', 10, 1000, valinit=nx, valstep=dx)
NY = Slider(axny, 'ny', 10, 1000, valinit=ny, valstep=dx)


l = ax.plot(X,Y,marker='o',markerfacecolor='None',markeredgecolor='k',linestyle="None")[0]

def update(val):
  #ax.clear()
  nx1 = NX.val
  ny1 = NY.val
  X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,nx1*dx,nx+1),np.linspace(0,ny1*dx,dx+1))
  ax.plot(X,Y,marker='o',markerfacecolor='None',markeredgecolor='k',linestyle="None")
  #l.set_xdata(X)
  #l.set_ydata(Y)
  fig.canvas.draw()
  fig.canvas.flush_events()

NX.on_changed(update)
NY.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    NX.reset()
    NY.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code somewhat. I made the number of dots smaller so that the effect was better visible. Do the cleaning on ax. Also added axis limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, Slider
import numpy as np

# - setup default grid values
nx = 20
ny = 10
dx = 2

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, nx * dx, nx + 1), np.linspace(0, ny * dx, ny + 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
ax.axis([0, nx + 1, 0, np.max(Y)])

axnx = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
axny = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])

NX = Slider(axnx, 'nx', 10, 100, valinit=nx, valstep=dx)
NY = Slider(axny, 'ny', 10, 100, valinit=ny, valstep=dx)

l = ax.plot(X, Y, marker='o', markerfacecolor='None', markeredgecolor='k', linestyle="None")[0]


def update(val):
    nx1 = NX.val
    ny1 = NY.val
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, nx1, nx1), np.linspace(0, ny1 * dx, ny1))
    ax.clear()
    ax.axis([0, nx1, 0, np.max(Y)])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    ax.plot(X, Y, marker='o', markerfacecolor='None', markeredgecolor='k', linestyle="None")


NX.on_changed(update)
NY.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')


def reset(event):
    NX.reset()
    NY.reset()


button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```